# Stop dash running on server

Tags: python, pandas, plotly-dash

I want now to stop dash from running on my localhost and want to change code, then to run it again and to see the updates (p.s. dash is not running if debug = True).

The option CTRL+C does not work and dash does not stop. If I try to change code then run it again it does not work.

Thank you in advance for your reply and help!

[image: Running dash on localhost]

Answer (score 4):

In Jupyter Notebook `Ctrl + C` does not terminate your running code. You could either write your code to a `.py` file and execute it from the command line for example

```
python dash.py
```

where `Ctrl + C` is working or if you prefer to stick to Jupyter Notebook you can terminate the execution by clicking in the Jupyter Notebook menu `Kernel --> Restart`, change the code and run the cell again.

Answer (score 0):

how about this, it kills the server, but i wish it would restart the kernel instead

```
import os, signal

os.kill(os.getpid(), signal.SIGTERM)
```